# Clojure, Haskell's Either Monad, and Sequences of Computation that Can Fail

Tags: clojure

## Abstract Problem:

I have a sequence of computations. Any step might fail. If a step fails, the entire process should be aborted with a message.

## Haskell Solution:

Either + IO Monads.

## (Known) Clojure Solutions:

1. Throw exceptions.
2. Use clojure/algo.monads

## Question:

Are there other solutions I should be aware of? What is the standard 'Clojure Way' to this problem?

## Concrete Example I'm Running Into:

I'm using https://github.com/kovasb/gamma to setup GLSL shaders in WebGL via ClojureScript. A typical program involves something like:

1. Allocate VertexShader object
2. Compile VertexShader.
3. Allocate FragmentShader object.
4. Compile FragmentShader
5. Allocate Program object.
6. Link Program
7. Use Program
8. Allocate VertexBufferObjects
9. Upload VertexBufferObject Data
10. Allocate TextureObject
11. Upload Texture
12. Setup Uniforms.
13. Make actual call.

    Any of these steps may fail (shader does not compile, no more BufferObjects left, wrong format, etc ...)

    And on failure, I want everything else to terminate, to get an error, and to fix it. What is the typical "Clojure Way" to handle this? (In Haskell, it's be EitherT IO Monad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to just use Java exceptions.  Catch upon an error and process however.

A small refinement is to use `with-exception-default` [from the Tupelo library.](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#default-value-in-case-of-exception)  An example use is like so:

```
(with-exception-default 666
  (Long/parseLong "123"))
;=> 123

(with-exception-default 666
  (Long/parseLong "12xy3"))
;=> 666
```

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure if it applies to your specific situation, the [some->](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some-%3E) macro is often used in Clojure for sequences of computations that can fail (where "fail" = "return nil").

Comment: This is a neat macro. Correct me if I'm wrong -- some-> passes the arg to the NEXT FORM, but I can't capture it, ie.. something of the form "x <- f(); y <- g(); z <- h(x, y)" can't work ... because when it comes to h, I only get passed y, and the "x" is lost.

Comment: You can maybe look at combining `some->` and `as->`: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/as-%3E#example-568eeddae4b0f37b65a3c280